# How to install Fiona for latest Python 3.9.6 to import geo pandas in Jupyter Notebook Python?

Tags: python, pandas, installation, geopandas

How can I install geo pandas in Jupyter Notebook?
I have the latest version of Python - 3.9.6 and I know that I need to download fiona or something like this but I have huge problem to do that because when I try: `pip install geopandas` I have an error.

I know that on stack there are many questions about that but on this page is Fiona only for python 3.7: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)

Could you write me step by step how to install geopandas on Jupyter Notebook ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up geopandas is a bit tricky. There are lots of dependencies which some of them require building if you use pip.

The best and easiest solution I suggest is using Miniconda or Anaconda to install geopandas.

Just install Miniconda from: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Then open miniconda prompt. In the command line create a new environment:

```
conda create --name gis python==3.9.6
```

After installation you need to activate your environment. The name of the enviroment as you can see in the command is `gis`:

```
conda activate gis
```

Then we need to install your packages:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas jupyterlab
```

Using conda-forge gives you the latest version. This will install all required packages at ones. It will also install jupyter lab.

To run the jupyter lab at your directory run the Miniconda prompt and change the directory:

```
cd <path to your directory>
```

The activate your environment:

```
activate gis
```

And run jupyter lab:

```
jupyter lab
```

Then you should see the ipykernel start and jupyter lab will show up in your default browser. The home directory of jupyter will be the one you set.

**Alternatives to Conda:**

If you want to use pip only you can install pipwin so it will get the wheel from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Also you can download wheels from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) yourself and install the package by using this command in your active environment:

```
pip install <path to the downloaded wheel>
```

you can see all required packages from here:

https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

Comment: One moment because I do not understand, what should I download from here there are many links: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ ????? in terms of conda ?

Comment: Conda is a package manager for python and especially for scientific python. The link was for fiona if you want to install it using the default package manager (pip). If you want to just install fiona you can look and find the fiona wheel for your vesion of python in that page and download the .whl file and install it.

Comment: just use the ctrl + f and search for fiona. You will find a findlabeled: Fiona‑1.8.20‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
Download that file and install it. This wheel is for python 3.9 64bit version. You may need to use other links for other python versions.